# How to use GNU parallel with ::: in the middle of the command

Tags: unix, parallel-processing

I would like to use GNU parallel to run a command for multiple systems.

The command would be:

```
nimadm -c <system> -l lppsource73 -s spot73 -o bosinst_migration -j nimadm_vg -d hdisk0 -Y
```

for  I have a list of systems in a variable.
I tried following in parallel:

```
parallel nimadm -c ::: $HOSTS -l lppsource73 -s spot73 -o bosinst_migration_73 -j nimadm_vg -d hdisk0 -Y
```

Unfortunately it is not working... parallel starts a job for everything after the ":::"

Can you help me please?
Thanks in advance...

best regards,
Joerg

Answer (score 2):

```
parallel nimadm -c {} -l lppsource73 -s spot73 -o bosinst_migration -j nimadm_vg -d hdisk0 -Y ::: $HOSTS
```

This is covered in:

- the cheatsheet https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_cheat.pdf
- the book https://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html or download it at: https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014 Read at least chapter 1+2. It should take you less than 20 minutes.
- the intro videos: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

If you want to dive deeper: spend a couple of hours walking through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). Your command line will love you for it.

You can also find a lot of examples of use in man parallel_examples.

Comment: Many thanks Ole...
didn't expect to get the answer directly from the author... nice :-)
regards,
Joerg